# Stop Button From Submitting Then Submit Form Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a delete button that I use globally in many areas of my site. Here is the code for it.

```
public function delete_button($id_to_be_deleted, $form_to_post_to, $button_name){
    return form_open($form_to_post_to, array('class'=>'table_form spanFormat')) .
    form_hidden(array('id'=>$id_to_be_deleted)) .
    form_submit(array('class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger','name'=>$button_name, 'value'=>'Delete', 'onclick'=>'confirmDelete();return false;')) .
    form_close();
}
```

This piece of code, `'onclick'=>'confirmDelete();return false;'` is what should temporarily stop the form from submitting and the run my function here,

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var d = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
    if (d) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

and if true, then submit the form.

For some reason it opens the popup but does not submit the form after because return false has already fired. But if I remove return false then the form will just submit and never pop open the popup.

Can anybody help me out?

Note: I want it done like this if possible. I do not want an on form submit, I want my handler from the button. This is because my delete forms all have different names but my buttons should all pop up this confirm dialog.

Comment: `'onclick'=>'return confirmDelete();'`

Comment: Lol, i'm so dumb. Thanks man. No wonder `confirmDelete()` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick is the wrong event to use. You want to hook the submit event, so let´s start with

```
<input type='submit' onclick="
```

Then you want to actually use the result of the confirmation, so return it directly:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="return confirm('sure?')"/>
```